# Count total and unique words from thousands of files

Tags: php, arrays, count, text-files, cpu-word

I have a large collection of text files over 5000 and there are more than 200,000 words. The problem is, when I try to combine the whole collection into a single array in order to find the unique words in the collection no output is shown(It is due to the very large size of array). The following piece of code works fine for small no. of collection e.g., 30 files but cannot operate on the very large collection. Help me fix this problem. Thanks

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
$directory = "archive/";
$dir = opendir($directory);
$file_array = array(); 
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
  $filename = $directory . $file;
  $type = filetype($filename);
  if ($type == 'file') {
    $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
    $text = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',  $contents);
    $text = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\n ]/', '', $text);
    $text = explode(" ", $text);
    $text = array_map('strtolower', $text);
    $stopwords = array("a", "an", "and", "are", "as", "at", "be", "by", "for", "is", "to");
    $text = (array_diff($text,$stopwords));
    $file_array = array_merge($file_array,  $text);
  }
}
closedir($dir); 
$total_word_count = count($file_array);
$unique_array = array_unique($file_array);
$unique_word_count = count($unique_array);
echo "Total Words: " . $total_word_count."<br>";
echo "Unique Words: " . $unique_word_count;
?>
```

Dataset of text files can be found here: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00217/C50.zip

Comment: Have you tried to make the memory limit higher?

Comment: I have a total 2GB of memory.

Comment: Have you tried to use an XML file or CSV?

Comment: Change your approach. Why would you load *everything* and then loop trough *everything*? What's wrong with doing it in chunks?

Comment: @N.B. I am not so expert in PHP :) . Would you help me to re-write this code to be read in chunks?

Comment: You can save some time and resources by removing `$str=implode($text, " ");` if you are not going to use `$str`.

Comment: There is no output either by removing `implode($text, " ");`

Comment: @user3814982 either you didn't show all the code, and `$str` is needed somewhere. Or you are making some small mistake when removing it.

Comment: perhaps rather than using text files you could use a db of some description a something like cassandra would be fine I guess rather than a full blown rdb then do your comparisons/counters/selectors against that

Comment: I know db is the solution. But I am finding a solution to this awkward work :)

Comment: I would **NOT** use a db for this, if the db is only used for this.

Comment: A good [mcve] never needs a zip file to provide clarity.  Why are you sanitizing the file contents on every read?!?  These files should be written with clean/ready data only.  Is there a reason you cannot maintain 27 files -- each with words that start with each letter of the alphabet and an extra file for all multibyte starting words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In stead of juggling with multiple arrays, just build one, and populate it only with the words and count them while you are inserting them. This will be faster, and you will even have the count per word.

By the way, you also need to add the empty string to the list of stopwords, or adjust your logic to avoid taking that one in.

```
<?php
$directory = "archive/";
$dir = opendir($directory);
$wordcounter = array();
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
  if (filetype($directory . $file) == 'file') {
    $contents = file_get_contents($directory . $file);
    $text = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',  $contents);
    $text = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\n ]/', '', $text);
    $text = explode(" ", $text);
    $text = array_map('strtolower', $text);
    foreach ($text as $word)
        if (!isset($wordcounter[$word]))
            $wordcounter[$word] = 1;
        else
            $wordcounter[$word]++;
  }
}
closedir($dir); 

$stopwords = array("", "a", "an", "and", "are", "as", "at", "be", "by", "for", "is", "to");
foreach($stopwords as $stopword)
    unset($wordcounter[$stopword]);

$total_word_count = array_sum($wordcounter);
$unique_word_count = count($wordcounter);
echo "Total Words: " . $total_word_count."<br>";
echo "Unique Words: " . $unique_word_count."<br>";

// bonus:
$max = max($wordcounter);
echo "Most used word is used $max times: " . implode(", ", array_keys($wordcounter, $max))."<br>";
?>
```

Comment: I suggest you add the following stop words: "the", "of", "in". If you do that you will have 53'993 unique words being used 1'957'286 times. The word "said" is used most with 39'973 times. This script ran in less than 8 seconds on my computer, processing your 5000 files (14.8MB).

Comment: I have a list of 28 stopwords.

Comment: Is there anyway to extract unique words from the mentioned collection into a single array? Your code is just extracting their frequencies.

Comment: @user3814982 Just use `array_keys($wordcounter)`

Answer (score 0):

Why combine all of arrays to one big useless array?

You can use [array_unique](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function to get unique values from array, than join it with next array from file and apply same function again.

Answer (score 0):

Do not increase the memory limit to high. This is typically not the best solution.

What you should so is to load the file line by line (which is easy in PHP when dealing with formats as CSV), compute that single line (or a small bunch a lines) and write to an output file. That way you can work on enormous amounts of input data with a small memory usage.

In any case try to find a way to split up the complete input into smaller chunks that can be worked on even without increasing the memory limit.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to load everything into a db table and then let the database server handle the most.

Or process rows in chunks and mark finished rows or aggregate them into another table.